# Django logging configurations

Tags: django, logging

I just finished getting logging working for DJANGO and was trying to find additional options available but havent found what I was looking for. In java.utils.logging there is a logging method: 
`java.util.logging.Logger.entering`

which is intended to be called when entering a method and

`java.util.logging.Logger.exiting`

which is called when leaving a method. Do these types of methods exist in DJANGO?

Also, currently I have the following verbose format settings set up in my settings.py:

```
<code>%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s</code>
```

Is it possible to get any information about the user to automatically get logged aka The username/email if it exists?

Also, in java you can can format your logging messages using [0] and fill in the variables with a object array.
Example:
`log.log( Level.FINER, "processing[{0}]: {1}", new Object[]{ i, list.get(i) } );`.

Does this kind of format exist in DJANGO logging at all?

Comment: Also, in java you can can format your logging messages using [0] and fill in the variables with a object array. Example <code>log.log( Level.FINER, "processing[{0}]: {1}", new Object[]{ i, list.get(i) } );</code>. Does this kind of format exist in DJANGO logging at all?

Answer (score 0):

Django just used Python's logging framework.

There are no `entering`/`leaving` methods in Python logging, as there is no need for them. For example, you could just do

```
logger.debug('Entering')
```

and

```
logger.debug('Leaving')
```

at the start/return from methods, and use `%(funcName)s` in the format string to indicate which method is being entered/exited.

If you want to display contextual information (such as user id or email) in the logs, see [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output).

In Python logging you don't need to pass arrays of `Object`, as you can do something like

```
logger.debug('processing [%s]: %s', i, list[i])
```